# How to rewrite my URL to items/category/item-name-itemid using mod rewrite?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my urls in this form: /items/category/item-name-id (the id is a number). Now my URL look like this: items.php?cat=category&name=item-name&id=12321

Oh and where I need to place the code for mod-rewrite ?

Comment: juat rewrite it in your code, changing items.php?cat=category&name=item-name&id=12321 to /items/category/item-name-id. Of course, you will need to back it up with some rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Enable these for debugging, disable when done (it's "expensive")
# RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
# RewriteLogLevel 9

# if the requested URI doesn't point to an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# .. pass it off to items.php (or index.php, or..) with the path as q,
# and whatever other GET parameters were there
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ items.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

mod_rewrite needs to be enabled obviously, and Apache conf needs to give you
"AllowOverride Options"
or
"AllowOverride All"

Now the string "/items/category/item-name-id" will arrive in your script as GET parameter 'q', where you can split on '/' and '-' as required, do table lookups for each element etc.

I tend to pass the q array (which it is after splitting it) to the first object (Category class), which loads the second (Name class), which loads the third etc. But that depends entirely on what you're going to do with them.