# Saving image urls

Tags: php, mysql, image-gallery

I have a website and I need to add an image gallery using mySQL and PHP. I know that I can save the image urls in a database with an id for each photo, but here's the question:
If I have a page with thumbnails of the pictures and I want each thumbnail to link to a page, for example: www.example.com/image/(id number) . How could I do that?

Comment: What aspect are you unsure about? How to map the URL?

Comment: Yea I need to know how to map the URL. Could you please help?

Comment: maybe @JMC's answer hits it; If you specifically ask about how to create a `/image/123` url, see e.g. this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477650/how-to-rewrite-my-url-to-items-category-item-name-itemid-using-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//$results = example: use sql to select the id and store the results into the $results variable.

foreach($results as $uno) {
    echo '<a href="http://domainname.com/images.php?id=' . $uno['id'] . '">'
}
```

Each links to images.php, and on *that* page, the `$_GET['id']` pulls the correct image from the database.

Comment: And what would happen if one went to domainname.com/images.php ?

Comment: Well that depends on how you write the code on that page.  You could either send people back to the homepage with ` if(!isset($_GET['id'])) header('Location: http://yourhomepage.com'); `. For better usability, you could simply display all of the thumbnails if ` $_GET['id'] ` is not set. This is the creative part of coding!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to generate the thumbnail and save  (in the same folder or in another one it is the same thing) in the upload process and save the path of the thumbnail along with the path of the full image and you can use any of them as you need.

If you don't generate the thumbnails in the upload process, you will have to generate them every time someone requests the page (it is a huge processing overload) so the performance of your website would be bad.

Comment: People won't be uploading pictures, I have specific pictures (about 52) that I will upload. And I already have the pictures as thumbnails in one folder and as big pictures in another.