# How to rewrite my URL so that it uses the names of category's and products?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using a .htaccess file to rewrite my URL. It removes the .php. That works fine. However, in my webshop system, I've got products, category's and main category's. I'd love to have my URL in this form:

> Home >> #NameOfMainCategory >> #NameOfCategory >> #TypenumberOfProduct

The original URL would be like this:

```
Webshop/product.php?$main_cat=Cables&cat=VideoCables&product=tup7
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477650/how-to-rewrite-my-url-to-items-category-item-name-itemid-using-mod-rewrite) topic, but it does not really help me out. How can I rewrite this url so that I would get this:

> Home/Cables/VideoCables/tup7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rewrite, you must first capture `(...)` the parts of the original request, and then use these parts `$1`, `$2`, ... in the target

```
RewriteRule ^Home/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ /Webshop/product.php?$main_cat=$1&cat=$2&product=$3 [L]
```